# Python regular expression search has unwanted characters

Tags: python, regex

In the python code below

```
import re

myText = "The color of the car is red. Which is a popular color."
regularExp = "The color of the car is\s*(?P<color>\w*)..*"
pattern = re.compile(regularExp)

match = re.search(pattern, myText)
color = match.groups("color")
print(color)
```

I expect the output to be `red`. But what I get is `('red',)`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You used `groups()`, use `group("color")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a tuple, not a str. Try this:

```
print(color[0])
```

or (Credit: Wiktor Stribiżew):

```
color = match.group("color")
print(color)
```

Answer (score 3):

re.search returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=match#match-objects) as you can see the `groups` method always returns a tuple. Therefore either access the first element of the result `color[0]` or use the `group` function instead:

```
color = match.group("color")
```

Also note that `match.groups("color")` does probably not do what you think it does, to quote the documentation:

> match.groups(default=None)
>
> The default argument is used for groups that did not participate in
> the match; it defaults to None.

Meaning you will set the color to "color" if no match is found for your color group.

Answer (score 0):

for match object `m`, `m.groups` returns a `tuple`, an immutable sequence. You can index it or

```
color = m.group(1) # m.group(n) for nth group
```

OR

```
color = m.group('color') # for named group
```

You said `('red',)` to have contained *unwanted* chars. This probably means you need to brush up basic python as you can't recognize a `tuple`.